# java wait() notify() вывести разговор по порядку

Tags: java, многопоточность, очередь-задач

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
    private static final String[] king =
            {"Вызывает антирес\nВаш технический прогресс:\nКак у вас там сеют брюкву —\nС кожурою али без?..",
                    "Вызывает антирес\nВаш питательный процесс:\nКак у вас там пьют какаву —\nС сахарином али без?..",
                    "Вызывает антирес\nИ такой ишо разрез:\nКак у вас там ходют бабы —\nВ панталонах али без?",
                    "Ты опять в свою дуду?\nСдам в тюрьму, имей в виду!\nЯ ж не просто балабоню,\nЯ ж политику веду!\nДевка эвон подросла,\nА тоща, как полвесла!\nВот и мыслю, как бы выдать\nНашу кралю за посла!\nТолько надо пользы для\nЗавлекать его не зля —\nДелать тонкие намеки\nНевсурьез и издаля."};
    private static final String[] nanny =
            {"Постеснялся хоть посла б!..\nАль совсем башкой ослаб?..\nГде бы что ни говорили —\nВсе одно сведет на баб!",
                    "Да за энтого посла\nДаже я бы не пошла,--\nТак и зыркает, подлюка,\nЧто бы стибрить со стола!\nОн тебе все \"Йес\" да \"йес\",\nА меж тем все ест да ест.\nОтвернись — он пол-Расеи\nЗаглотнет в один присест!"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object sync = new Object();
        new Thread(() -> {
            synchronized (sync) {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        sync.notify();
                        if (i == 2) {
                            new Thread(() -> {
                                synchronized (sync) {
                                    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                                        sync.notify();
                                        System.out.println("Нянька:\n" + nanny[j] + "\n");
                                        try {
                                            sync.wait();
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Царь:\n" + king[i] + "\n");
                        sync.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(() -> {
            synchronized (sync) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    sync.notify();
                    System.out.println("Посол:\nЙес!" + "\n");
                    try {
                        sync.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Программа используя 3 или более потоков должна вывести разговор:
Царь
Вызывает антирес
Ваш технический прогресс:
Как у вас там сеют брюкву —
С кожурою али без?..
Посол
Йес!
Царь
Вызывает антирес
Ваш питательный процесс:
Как у вас там пьют какаву —
С сахарином али без?..
Посол
Йес!
Царь
Вызывает антирес
И такой ишо разрез:
Как у вас там ходют бабы —
В панталонах али без?
Посол
Йес!
Нянька
Постеснялся хоть посла б!..
Аль совсем башкой ослаб?..
Где бы что ни говорили —
Все одно сведет на баб!
Царь
Ты опять в свою дуду?
Сдам в тюрьму, имей в виду!
Я ж не просто балабоню,
Я ж политику веду!
Девка эвон подросла,
А тоща, как полвесла!
Вот и мыслю, как бы выдать
Нашу кралю за посла!
Только надо пользы для
Завлекать его не зля —
Делать тонкие намеки
Невсурьез и издаля.
Нянька
Да за энтого посла
Даже я бы не пошла,--
Так и зыркает, подлюка,
Что бы стибрить со стола!
Он тебе все "Йес" да "йес",
А меж тем все ест да ест.
Отвернись — он пол-Расеи
Заглотнет в один присест!

Но в результате получаю:

Царь:
Вызывает антирес
Ваш технический прогресс:
Как у вас там сеют брюкву —
С кожурою али без?..

Посол:
Йес!

Царь:
Вызывает антирес
Ваш питательный процесс:
Как у вас там пьют какаву —
С сахарином али без?..

Посол:
Йес!

Царь:
Вызывает антирес
И такой ишо разрез:
Как у вас там ходют бабы —
В панталонах али без?

Посол:
Йес!

Царь:
Ты опять в свою дуду?
Сдам в тюрьму, имей в виду!
Я ж не просто балабоню,
Я ж политику веду!
Девка эвон подросла,
А тоща, как полвесла!
Вот и мыслю, как бы выдать
Нашу кралю за посла!
Только надо пользы для
Завлекать его не зля —
Делать тонкие намеки
Невсурьез и издаля.

Нянька:
Постеснялся хоть посла б!..
Аль совсем башкой ослаб?..
Где бы что ни говорили —
Все одно сведет на баб!

Comment: Здесь прекрасно все. И вопрос, в котором нет вопроса. И ответ, в котором нет ответа.

Comment: @tym32167 Ну уж извините) Голова совсем не работала, не знал как сформулировать вопрос. В голове это выглядело более понятно)

Comment: Просто вопросы без вопросов я вижу часто, но чтобы был ответ без ответа, который ещё и помог - это редкость. Но ваша проблема решилась, уже хорошо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону java.util.concurrent.Phaser.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало, немного не то что требовалось по заданию, но думаю подойдёт.